# Redirect user based upon HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, http-referer

I am trying to redirect users on my site that come from a certian referal site to have a special message. I have this:

```
<?php $REFERER = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

  if ($REFERER == "http://www.url.com/") { 
?>

Content Goes Here

?>    
    }
?>
```

And they do not get the message

I did a test and did it from one of my other sites and echoed what the  `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` put out and changed the above code to match it exactly and it worked but I think the issue I am having is the output of the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` is not EXACTLY the same. For instance if they were on the page `www.domain.com/page2/index.php` the referrer would be `http://www.domain.com/page2/`

is there a way to make it so people that come from www.domain.com no matter whats after the / ?!?

UPDATE:

I tried all the first 2 answers and could not get it to work (possibly my fault) so i did some research from what they sent and created this:

```
<?php 
    $mystring = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
    $findme   = 'domain'; 
    $pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    } else {
    echo "content";
 ?>
```

Is there anything wrong with this option as it seems to work?

Comment: Hi Brandon.  I see that you have asked several questions (with some having answers) yet you have not accepted any.  Please score the answers appropriately and click the checkmark when one has satisfied what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know I was suppose to do so! You betcha I will!

Comment: Yup, no worries!  You're new... it is very common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the string starts with `http://www.url.com/`

```
if (strpos($REFERER, "http://www.url.com/") === 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

A real simple one would be:

```
if (strpos($REFERER, "www.url.com") !== false) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's `parse_url` function:

```
<?php $REFERER =  parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_PATH);

    if ($REFERER['host'] == "www.url.com") { 
?>
```